# Pivot table column rename

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to rename my pivot columns in SQL Server i.e.

```
for days in ([22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28]
```

Is there a way to do that?

This is my query:

```
select *
from 
    (select
         day(date) as days,
         temp 
     from 
         temperature) as t
pivot
    (max(temp) 
        for days in ([22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28])
    ) as pivot_table
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly by `rename pivot columns` ? Do you mean the column in the result ?

Comment: Yes i want to rename the columns from integer 22 to twenty-two, 23 to twenty-three and so on.

Comment: `SELECT [22] as [twenty-two], [23] as [twenty-three], . . .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Squirel recommended:

```
select [22] as [twenty-two], [23] as [twenty-three] ...
from (
    select
         day(date) as days,
         temp 
    from temperature) as t
pivot(max(temp) 
      for days in ([22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28])
) as pivot_table
```